# Customize switch language shortcut

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, input-language

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a new HP pavilion laptop.
As I did before, I entered to `Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing` and tried to set Switch to next source to function with `Alt+Shift L`.

From some reason, I get instead `Alt+Mod2+Shift L`, and the `Alt+Shift L` combitation does not do anything.

Apart, I also want the operation to be cyclic, i.e.:

```
Lang1 -> Lang2 -> Lang3 -> Lang1
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I get the same in the System Settings GUI on my 16.04, but OTOH switching sources with `Alt+Shift L` still works fine for me. Does the default shortcut `Super+Space` work for you?

Comment: Yes, `Super+Space` works fine...

Comment: It is strange.  The combination `Super+Space` appears like this in the keyboard shortcuts panel. However, I tried `Super+Shift L` and got `Mod2+Mod4+Super+Hyper+Shift L`. And it doesn't work...

Comment: You can try to find setting in `gnome-tweak-tool` in *Typing* tab. Or if it does not work - switch to normal comprehensive desktop such as [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/gallery/1.14/MATE-1.14_8.png).

Comment: Cannot find the corresponding entry for language switch under "Typing" tab @N0rbert

Comment: Sometime ago it has modifier-only shortcuts. No idea. But MATE DE has this functionality. See my [question on community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/3?u=norbert). On my machines I use simple `Ctrl+Shift` and `Alt+Shift` - they work as expected.

Comment: For your information - we talk about well known [bug 1218322](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322) here. And what is interesting `Alt+Shift` is normally set and usable on 16.04 LTS with Unity desktop, but not on GNOME FlashBack sessions.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to set it. Please try this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle']"
```

Comment: It didn't help. Before I did it, i checked `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` and got `@as []`.  After executing `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle']"` I ran again `gsettings get...` and got `['grp:alt_shift_toggle']`. In the `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` I still see the value I had before in both `Switch to next/previous source` fields, and testing the combination nothing happens.

Comment: @guyaloni: I see. This is an alternative way which works for me on 17.10, and yes, it does not change the value in Settings, but it's supposed to override it. Sorry to hear that this didn't work for you either.